# How to get current path in the flow using dataweave in Mulesoft 4?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I want to get "orders" path resource from the requested url below.

Sample: 
       localhost:8082/orders?id=2

Comment: did you tried to retrieve URI parameters ?

Comment: you need to really start looking into RAML for your project. it will outline all the endpoints, query parameters and other important details for that specific endpoint.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Are you using only an http listener? Or also apikit and raml? Show some snippets of the flow also.